# DbUpdateException was unhandle by user code

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have such code in controller:

```
public string UpdateDapAnColumnSelected(int bode, int cauhoi, int selected, int userId)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(bode + " " + cauhoi + ", dap an: " + selected + "user Id: " + userId);

        //add to database THi
        THI updateThi = new THI();
        updateThi.MABODE = bode;
        updateThi.MACAUHOI = cauhoi;
        updateThi.MADAPAN = selected;
        updateThi.USERID = userId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.THIs.Add(updateThi);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "a";
        }
        return "a";
    }
```

In the model context I have:

```
public virtual DbSet<THI> THIs { get; set; }
```

Class THI in Model:

```
 public partial class THI
{
    public int USERID { get; set; }
    public int MABODE { get; set; }
    public int MACAUHOI { get; set; }
    public int MADAPAN { get; set; }
}
```

I can't save updateThi to database. Can you help me? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: What exception in throwing? Show us also your model or/and viewmodel to check correctness there as well.

Comment: Dear magos,
I updated class THI in Model.

Comment: Why do you `Add` the new object to `db.THIs` when you want to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You published only partial class of THI, so it's difficult to deduce is Id of THI class unique.

This exception is often caused by attemption to add duplicated primary key. You should have Id or THIID property to follow EF conventions. Thanks to that PK will be configured as an identity column.

Let me know does it work.

===EDIT===

And what is more - you're using Add method to update entity. You shouldn't, because then Id for sure will not be unique. EF will try to add the same record with identical Id into the database once again. Simply update properties and call SaveChanges, without Add() method.